# Elasticsearch respository shows no snapshots after upgrade from 2.x to 5.x

Tags: elasticsearch, repository, upgrade, snapshot

On a RHEL6 system, I followed the steps laid out [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) to create a repository and capture a snapshot prior to my upgrade. I verified the existence of the snap shot:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_snapshot/_all?pretty=true'
```

Which gave me the following result:

> {   "upgrade_backup" : {
>       "type" : "fs",
>       "settings" : {
>         "compress" : "true",
>         "location" : "/tmp/elasticsearch-backup"
>   } } }

After upgrading Elasticsearch via yum, I went to restore my snapshot but none are showing up:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_snapshot/_all?pretty=true'
```

> {  }

I checked on the file system and see the repository files:

```
ls -lrt /tmp/elasticsearch-backup
```

> total 24
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch 121 Apr  7 14:42 meta-snapshot-number-one.dat
>   drwxr-xr-x. 3 elasticsearch elasticsearch  21 Apr  7 14:42 indices
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch 191 Apr  7 14:42 snap-snapshot-number-one.dat
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  37 Apr  7 14:42 index
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch 188 Apr  7 14:51 index-0
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch   8 Apr  7 14:51 index.latest
>   -rw-r--r--. 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch  29 Apr  7 14:51 incompatible-snapshots

I made sure elasticsearch.yml still has the "data.repo" tag, so I'm not sure where to look or what to do to determine what happened, but somehow my snapshots vanished!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following line to `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
path.repo: ["/tmp/elasticsearch-backup"]
```

Then restart Elastic service and create a new snapshots repository:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:92000/_snapshot/backup" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
    "type": "fs",
    "settings": {
        "location": "/tmp/elasticsearch-backup",
        "compress": true
    }
}'
```

Now you should be able to list all snapshots in your repository and eventually restore them:

```
curl -s -XGET "localhost:9200/_snapshot/backup/_all" | jq .
```